# how to initialize 'array of object' with constructor in a similar way for 'an object'

Tags: c++, arrays

if there is one object, we can initialize it with constructor in the following way -

```
class obj{
int x;

public:
obj(int n) {x=n;}
};

int main()
{
   obj p(2);
}
```

Is there an exact same way for array of object; and I mean an exact same way.

I know about other two way to initialize an object with constructor -

```
obj p = obj(2);
obj p = 2; // for one parameter constructor
```

and there equivalent way to initialize array of object -

```
obj p = {obj(1), obj(2), obj(3), obj(4)};
obj p[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

but I failed to find a similar way for initializing array of object shown in the first code for a single object.

Comment: it seems to work fine with obj p[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; :/

Comment: @NathanOliver [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f0c7db5ebd609de)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right...

```
// Initialize array member varible - method 1
struct Foo
{
   int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

// Initialize array member varible - method 2
struct Bar
{
   Bar() : a{1, 2, 3} {}
   int a[3];
};

// Can't do this.
struct Foo
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
};
```

Comment: did not understand the second method.

Comment: The second method is similar to initialize members that are not of type array. If you had a member `int b;`, you can initialize it with `b{20}` in the member initializer section of the constructor.

Comment: i did not know structure has constructor section :/ and what's the colon for?

Comment: @SyedNakibHossain, `struct` and `class` behave in very similar manner. The major difference is that the default access of `struct`s is `public` while the default access of `class` is `private`.

Comment: @SyedNakibHossain the colon is for the member initializer list: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list/926795#926795

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
#include <array>
class obj{
  int x;

 public:
  obj(int n) {x=n;}
};

int main()
{
   std::array<obj,3> p = {3, 7, 11};
}
```

std::array gives you same semantics as a primitive array type but qualifies as a c++ *container*. You would probably be better off using std::vector, which offers dynamic re-sizing and more protection:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<obj> p = {obj(1), obj(2), obj(4)};
```

The nice thing about using generic containers is you can often use them interchangably:

```
#include <vector>
//#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
...
int main()
{
   std::vector<obj> p = {obj(1), obj(2), obj(4)};     
   // or the following:
   // std::array<obj,3> p = {obj(1), obj(2), obj(4)};

   // either one of the above will work here
   std::for_each(begin(p), end(p), 
                [](obj const & o){ std::cout << o.x << " "; });
                std::cout << std::endl;
   //           ^^^ yes, this only works if x is public
}
```

Note that std::array is sized at compile time so it does require that you tell it the number of elements.

You could also rewrite the original class to use initializer list construction as follows:

```
class obj{
  int x;
 public:
  obj(int n) : x(n) { }
};
```

Even in this example it might help because it allows you to make `x` `const`. In general it has a lot of benefits and is a good habit to get into.